# Toggle use of class implementation in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a C++ program A.cpp and I'm  including two header files X.h and Y.h. This program(A.cpp) has a class 'foo' and the prototypes of all members of that class. The implementation of this class is done in X.h and Y.h. Both of them contain different definitions of the member functions. But the inclusion of one these files is done conditionally using #ifdef in the program. So if a certain condition is satisified, X.h is #include-ed, else Y.h is #include-ed. Both of them are never included together. Here's the problem: I need to change this compile-time toggle to run-time toggle. I know a header file cannot be included during run-time, so is there any way in which I can "choose" which implementation I want, without using namespaces? Overloading is ruled out, because the functions' prototypes are the same.

Thanks a lot.
(Sorry if this is stupid. I a newbie in C++)

Comment: Sounds like you really want polymorhpic behavior.  If only there was a way...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll go with the subclassing.

Comment: Why are you putting your declarations in a .cpp file and your definitions in .h files? It should be the other way around.

Comment: I'll throw in the keyword `strategy pattern`. Should get you some results.

Answer (score 3):

If you want two different behaviours at runtime, then it sounds like you're describing *polymorphism*.  Consider writing two different classes that inherit from a common base-class with virtual functions.  Then at runtime you can do things like this:

```
Animal &a = (x == 3) ? Dog() : Cat();

a.talk();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to consider a static [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)? You can have a single method which returns the instance of your choice to the caller. You would need to subclass as OliCharlesworth suggests, then this would make it transparent to the calling code.

In pseudocode.

```
class baseclass{
...
static baseclass *GimmeImpl(){
    if(aImpl){
       return A();
    }else{
       return B();
    }

}

};

class A:public baseclass {...};
class B:public baseclass {...};
```